# Restrict Max number of TabItems in WPF Tab control

Tags: wpf, tabs

Is there any way I can restrict max number of Tabs in a WPF Tab control? In my application there is feasibility to users to create Tabs dynamically in the tab control. I want to restrict this to say 20 tabs, is there any event or property I can use?
Thanks

Comment: Can't you use `TabControl.Items.Count` to see the current number of tabs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer is `No`, there is no provision to restrict the number of tabs in TabControl. Theoretical maximum count would be `int.MaxValue()`.

You may rethink about the UI solution for the given problem.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple.You can define a property.When user create a tab.It plus one.And when a tab close.It minus one.You can judge the tab count in the dynamic crate tab code.